# using IIS to access a Dreamweaver behavior to use PayPal?

Tags: iis-7

I downloaded an interesting behavior from the Dreamweaver site that gives full ordering information over to PayPal and it seems to work like a champ except that it requires an external site (http://) to access an external error/cancel page. How do I address such a page using IIS? IIS is installed properly and I can access it through "localhost", getting the spiffy splash screen.

Comment: Seems like a question for SF or Pro Webmasters.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it figured out, sort of.apparently there is a problem in getting Dreamweaver to write/rewrite a file on the local host on the local host with the access control list (ACL) – when I create or edit a file in Dreamweaver it creates/re-creates/rewrites the file within ACL allowing only the administrator read/write permission. Any idea of how to set up the ACL with read permission to EveryOne set to allow? As a default. I have looked through all of the preferences in Dreamweaver as well as the local security profile. Obviously I'm missing something – any idea?

Ross